# PHP smarty row hide easily

Tags: php, html, smarty, tablerow

i have a bit of code that is supposed to show a row if it has a certain value. i am new in this HTML / PHP / SMARTY world and cant see how to fix this in an easy way.
my code looks like this:

```
<tr>
other data to be defined before the code under this.
{foreach from=$data item=item2 }
{if isset ($data)}
{if (strpos($item.to, 'given stringk')) == true}
hide row
{else}
hide row
{/if}
{else}
do not hide row
</tr>
```

i cant seem to figure this out. any ideas?

Comment: `$data` should be always defined inside a loop of `$data`. `strpos` returns an integer or false if the needle isnt found. Your if construct would only be true if the strpos result is >= 1 (position starts by 0). dependend on your smarty version you should better do `{if $item.to|strpos:'given stringk' !== false}`

Answer (score 1):

As @sofl mentioned you should rather use `!== false` instead of `== true` because if string begins with. The whole code should work fine.

I've prepared sample script and it works fine:

PHP file:

```
$x = array (
   array ('to' => 'given string'),
   array ('to' => 'givenNOstring'),
   array ('to' => 'givenNOstring2'),
   array ('to' => 'given string2'),

);

$smarty->assign('data', $x);
```

Smarty template file:

```
<tr>
other data to be defined before the code under this.<br />
{foreach from=$data item=item2 }
{if (strpos($item2.to, 'given string')) !== false}
hide row {$item2.to}<br />
{else}
do not hide row {$item2.to}<br />
{/if}
{/foreach}
</tr>
```

Output is:

```
other data to be defined before the code under this.
hide row given string
do not hide row givenNOstring
do not hide row givenNOstring2
hide row given string2
```

as expected so it works fine